# Search for value in dataframe that contains a list

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this :

```
id  points
a   [c,v,b,n]
b   []
c   [x,a]
....
```

and a dictionary (i also have it as dataframe):

```
{'a': ['j','c'],
 'b': [p,r,q]
 'c': [n,k,l,x,a]
 ....}
```

I want to search if the key of the dictionary is contained is the points of the dataframe and then remove the items from dictionary points that there is no match in the dictionary.Expected output:

```
id  points
a   [c]
b   []
c   [x,a]
```

I tried this

```
for key,point in my_dict.items():
    if df['points'].str.contains(point).any()
```

but i get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

I tried converting the dataframe to a dictionary but then the search time is too much because i need more for loops. Any suggestions for code  or data structure improvements?

**Edit**

Another representation of the data :

```
id  points
a   [c,v,b,n]
b   []
c   [x,a]
....
```

and

```
points
j,c
p,r,q
n,k,l,x,a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `apply` and convert your dict values into a set can convert the `intersection` to a list:

```
In [15]:
d={'a': ['j','c'],
 'b': ['p','r','q'],
 'c': ['n','k','l','x','a']}
d

Out[15]:
{'a': ['j', 'c'], 'b': ['p', 'r', 'q'], 'c': ['n', 'k', 'l', 'x', 'a']}

In [17]:
df['points'] = df.apply(lambda row: list(set(d[row['id']]).intersection(row['points'])), axis=1)
df

Out[17]:
  id  points
0  a     [c]
1  b      []
2  c  [a, x]
```

As to why you get an error, you're trying to call a `.str` method on a Series that is a dtype list, they are not strings.

Comment: I am getting a key error. Is there any other solution using the two dataframes i added to my post?

Comment: can you post raw input data and all code to reproduce your dfs and what you've tried that raised the error

Comment: Sorry as i was double checking before posting i found my error. That was very helpful! Thanks!